# Cómo usar en un cliente React, una imagen descargada de S3 bucket con un servidor node.js?

Tags: reactjs, imagen

Tengo una imagen que descargo de S3 bucket con Node.js. Mi cliente React, usa el metodo fetch() para pedir la imagen al servidor. Quiero usar esa imagen en el metodo render() de un componente en React.Mi problema es que no consigo que la imagen se vea en el "web browser" porque la estoy empleando incorrectamente. Al usar Postman, obtengo como respuesta la imagen.
Mi codigo se ve asi:

```
//Descargar imagen de s3 bucket:

download:  async (fileKey)=>{

        const downloadParams={
            Key:fileKey,
            Bucket:bucketName
        }
        return await  s3.getObject(downloadParams).createReadStream()
    }
```

```
//El sevidor manada la imagen al cliente
getBackgroundCheck:async (req,res)=>{
        const readStream = await s3.download(req.params.key)
        console.log(readStream)
      
        readStream.pipe(res)
        
         
    }
```

```
//el cliente require la imagen del servidor despues del evento "submit" en un formulario
const getBackgroundFile = async (e) => {

    try {
        e.preventDefault()
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/adminPanel/getbackgroundcheck/${id}`)
console.log(response)        
setImage(response)
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

```
//console.log(response) from getBackgroundFile():
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:3003/adminPanel/getbackgroundcheck/6239f7443bcd29a87af789e8', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3003/adminPanel/getbackgroundcheck/6239f7443bcd29a87af789e8"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

De acuerdo con mi logica, puedo guardar la respuesta en una variable de estado.

```
const[image, setImage] = useState('')
//Luego en el metodo render espero usar la imagen asi:
<img src= {image} alt=''/>
```

Lo anterior, da como resultado que no se vea nada en el web browser y que al inspeccionar el DOM en el image tag vea lo siguiente:

Comment: Hola, podrías hacer un console.log(response) antes del setImage(response) y mostrar lo que te devuelve?

Comment: Claro este es lo que devuelve:  Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:3003/adminPanel/getbackgroundcheck/6239f7443bcd29a87af789e8', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: "cors"url: "http://localhost:3003/adminPanel/getbackgroundcheck/6239f7443bcd29a87af789e8"[[Prototype]]: Response

Comment: Por lo que interpreto estas colocando en Image el response completo, deberías pasarle al setImage la imagen (base64 por ejemplo) que seguro te está llegando en Response.data. Espero te sirva!